# Trouble moving data into EAX

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I am assigning a variable via input and then trying to move that variables value into EAX.

It is not working, and I am getting strange results.

```
    .386
    .model flat, c
    .stack 100h
printf PROTO arg1:Ptr Byte, printlist:VARARG
scanf PROTO arg2:Ptr Byte, printlist:VARARG
    .data
in1fmt byte "%d",0
msg1fmt byte 0Ah,"%s",0
msg1 byte "Enter an integer: ",0
number sdword ?
    .code
main proc
    INVOKE printf, ADDR msg1fmt, ADDR msg1
    INVOKE scanf, ADDR in1fmt, ADDR number
    mov eax, number
    ret
main endp
    end
```

If I input 30, EAX contains 17 for some reason.

Why?

Comment: How are you checking the value of eax?  I don't see any output code....

Comment: maybe he checked in the debugger

Comment: or also, maybe he typed 23 .__.

Comment: what does the generated assembly look like (in your binary)?

Answer (score 0):

Try a dd or DWORD rather than a signed DWORD.  See this example:

http://www.masm32.com/board/index.php?PHPSESSID=6a490c9d234761060af337f831a7efbe&topic=3270;prev_next=next